# Links that expire

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

So basically I'm doing a password reset and want to set a time limit. Here's the code I have

```
$time = time();
$hash = md5($id . $time . "somerandomsalt"); // check this again in activation.php
$link = "activation.php?id=" . $id . "&hash=" . $hash . "&time=" . $time;
```

Would this be safe? All I want to do is make the link expire after say 1 hour. I also have this code that generates a token (I think this code is more secure).

```
$rand = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16); // take 8 random bytes
$token = substr(sha1($rand), 0, 49);
```

The issue is I'm not sure how to make say

```
http://localhost:8888/forgot/activate.php?token=467e65833fc977767d5b000929d1229fa5eaf309
```

Expire after a certain time. Any ideas?

Comment: You could check Datetime in your controller

Comment: Well once I store the date in the DB. How would I find out how old it is? @ManoloSalsas

Comment: record the timestamp when you store it in your db...

Comment: Well I'm basically asking how I'd compare the timestamp with the current time @Fabricator

Comment: Suposse datetime stored. If new Datetime() < $stored ...

Comment: When you create the token and store it inside the database you can make use of an auto-increment column to get an id that you can use in the URL to match it against

Comment: `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, created_at) < 1`

Comment: @Fabricator Putting the time condition in the query will make it more difficult to distinguish between expired tokens and non-existent tokens.

Comment: @Jack, `select TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, created_at) < 1 live from tokens ...`

Comment: Also any ideas on how to make this work nicely? You seem to know a lot with PHP security @Jack

Comment: @Fabricator I suppose that's okay, assuming that the MySQL server lives in the same timezone as the web server ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the safest way is store the generation time of the hash in the database. So you would have two columns: `token` and `token_created_at` (name doesn't matter). When the user clicks the link, you query database for the `token` and compare `token_created_at` to the current time. If the difference is more than an hour, raise an error.

**Edit:** To find the difference, create a `DateTime` object from `token_created_at`, and add 1 hour to it to get the expiration time. Then compare it to the current time. If current time is less than the expiration time, then it means the token is valid, otherwise it has expired. The code would look like this:

```
$token_created_at = new DateTime('2014-06-28 03:14:07');
$expires_at = $token_created_at->modify('+1 hour');

$current_time = new DateTime();

if ($current_time < $expires_at) {
  // Token is valid.
} else {
  // Token has expired.
}
```

Comment: Well thanks for a great answer. My question basically is how would I find the difference? And how would I get the time? `$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());`?

Comment: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` gives you the equivalent of the MySQL datetime or timestamp types. 

You can compare using a SQL query, or extract the `token_created_at` into a PHP variable, run `strtotime()` on it, and compare it to `time()`.

Comment: So I'd do an if else statement. Right? And what would I check though. Would I minus the current time from the time in the DB? @jsickles

Comment: It would be a good idea to have three columns in the table actually; id, hash and created time.

Comment: When I roll back an hour or two like this `2014-06-28 01:14:07` I still get that it's valid. Shouldn't it be expired by then? Its an hour before it expires, right? Also when I do `2014-06-28 05:14:07` for example its still valid

Comment: I have an `ID`, `USER`, `TOKEN`, and `token_created_at`. That look fine? @Jack

Comment: @user3100859 Yeah, that looks dandy ... you could additionally set a UNIQUE constraint on USER so that you can't have more than one reset token per user (or rather, the latest overwrites the previous ones).

Comment: @user3100859 What's your current time? Can you do a `print_r($current_time);`?

Comment: I get `DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-06-27 23:10:16 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York )`. @GergoErdosi

Comment: @user3100859 Ok, so it's not 28 in your timezone yet. Token creation time can't be in the future. Make two tests: 1. Set the initial time to the current time `2014-06-27 23:10:16`. 2. Set it to two hours earlier: `2014-06-27 21:10:16`. This should give you the expected result.

Comment: `$token_created_at = new DateTime('2014-06-27 21:10:16');` and `$current_time = '2014-06-27 23:10:16';` still return that its Valid.

Comment: No, don't change `$current_time`. 1. Set `$token_created_at = new DateTime('2014-06-27 23:10:16');`. Test the code. Token should be valid. 2. Set `$token_created_at = new DateTime('2014-06-27 21:10:16');`. Test the code. Token should be invalid.